# Is "this.getOptions is not a function" a bug for webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, webpack-cli

I have a node.js backend project, and I use `webpack` to build it.

```
"webpack": "^4.46.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.4.0"
```

it reports error like

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

Then I read the source code of `/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js` to figure out why.

[image: Screenshot of the source code with problem]

As you can see in the screenshot, there's only one search result of `this.getOptions()` in the `node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js` file. No definition of the function and it just be used. It's supposed to be a bug, at least it looks like that.

Why does the `babel team` write souce code like that? And why do all others think it's a version conflict but not a code bug itself?

Comment: Which version of babel-loader are you using and why have you been ignoring the warning about the Webpack peer dependency?

Answer (score 2):

See [getOptions method for Loaders](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#getoptions-method-for-loaders)

> Webpack 5 ships with built-in [`this.getOptions`](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#thisgetoptionsschema) method available in loader context. This is a breaking change for loaders that had been using `getOptions` method from previously preferred [`schema-utils`](https://github.com/webpack/schema-utils):

> `this.getOptions` is available since Webpack 5

`babel-loader` 9.x supports webpack 5.x, since it uses [`this.getOptions`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/b89dfbd3bca9154ebee6d8ea10f99b7722a0125c/src/index.js#L57)

If you want to use webpack 4.x, then you should use `babel-loader` 8.x which supports webpack 4.x or 5.x. `babel-loder` 8.x uses [`loaderUtils.getOptions(this)`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/blob/9bf5652c3b718971382c110c4b7f86212aa8cb52/src/index.js#L58)

The version compatibility instructions are very clear on the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader)